# xCode indenting driving be batty

Tags: xcode

I use xCode as my C editor for a small makefile project I'm working on. I keep noticing during Git commits that the whitespace is being changed on me. Here's an example:

```
void parse_key_values(Card *card, Errors *errors)
{
     char str[MAX_LINE_LEN];
     char key[MAX_LINE_LEN], value[MAX_LINE_LEN];
```

Although difficult to see, if you cursor through this you will notice there is a single 2-space-wide tab *and a space* at the front of the lines. The tab is correct and what I would expect to see. I have no idea where the space is coming from. When I remove it manually and re-indent, it re-inserts it.

Here is my setup:

[image]

I have tried changing "prefer tabs" to "prefer spaces", and then goes ahead and inserts three spaces.

I suspected that it was counting the opening brace and indenting from there, but then noticed the same problem on code like this:

```
  if(split != NULL) {
     if (split[0] == '=') split++;
     if (split[0] == ':') split++;
```

This is driving me crazy, and causing all sorts of annoyance during commits. Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Looks like `char str[MAX_LINE_LEN];` is aligned below the function name. I noticed similar behavior in Swift´s `guard`-statements in recent updates of Xcode. Unfortunately, I didn't find anything in Xcode's preferences that could affect that. Though, funny enough, I could't reproduce the described behavior in C-code: I copied your settings exactly, and in my Xcode 13.2.1 your code snippets look like as you would expect.

Answer (score -1):

*sigh*

So right over on the right side of the screen is this little bit of UI:

[image]

Somehow, and it absolutely was not deliberate, the second of those two settings was changed to "3", so xcode was doing precisely what it was told to do.

Having never used that field, *ever*, I have never even looked at it. I'm still lost as to how I managed to change it.